# Windows 8 logon screen, is this a real place? if so where is it?

Tags: windows, authentication

This is a standard windows 8 logon screen, is this a real place? if so where is it?
[image: windows logon screen]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. But to answer your question, the real place is the Space Needle in Seattle.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying a geographical location (not programmatically).

Comment: This is not a question about programming but many programmer which don't live in the united states might find it a good question since they see this image everyday and some of them (like I do) might wonder where is this place on earth. I think that many programmers are interested in environment they are using not less than the tools they are developing and the methodology of how to develop those tools (the so called classic programming questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tower is the Space Needle in Seattle (see www.spaceneedle.com).  As you might guess, downtown Seattle does *not* look like the green and beautiful landscape that is shown next to it.  Though Washington state does have awesomely beautiful mountains and ocean.

Comment: The Space Needle also isn't quite that ... large. Typical artwork that highly exaggerates certain features for a desired effect (although I'm  sure I don't know exactly what that effect is supposed to be...).